# How to calculate how many levels I gain given my Paragon level, server level and amount of unclaimed Battle Pass points in Diablo Immortal?

Tags: diablo-immortal

I'm aiming for Paragon 1000 and I want to find out *when* to claim my Battle Pass points. I will have first clear raid bosses available and first clear Gauntlet, so I will save them for last.

For example, I am p982 atm and I have about 2k unclaimed points in BP. After next week numbers will be different and I want to know how to calculate what level I will end up when claiming xp points from BP.

I really want to avoid ending up in say level p998 after raids and gauntlet, as the ow grind will be so much harder.